# wanting to know how to easily add sums from a checkbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, checkbox, textbox

im extremely new to c# so im having a little difficulty with the following problem.

below is my following code

```
int access = 1;
int onlineVideos = 2;
int personalTrainer = 20;
int dietConsultation = 20;

int extras = 0;

if (checkBox1.Checked)
{
    extras += access;
}
else if (checkBox2.Checked)
{
    extras += onlineVideos;
}
else if (checkBox3.Checked)
{
    extras += personalTrainer;
}
else if (checkBox4.Checked)
{
    extras += dietConsultation;
}

textBox6.Text = extras.ToString();
```

i want to be able to easily add the sums of all the boxes that are checked, and then print them to a textbox.

Comment: Are you sure you want "else if", since that will only allow for one checkbox to be counted?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I want to be able to add all the numbers of the checkboxes that are ticked, so that the final sum that is printed in the textbox is the total of the checkboxes ticked.

Comment: I am aware of my first issue, using if else statements. but i am not sure what other way would be better, which is why I am struggling. A bit of guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: "I want to do X" is a goal. "I want to do X, but can't because of Y" - Y is the problem. That's what you should be telling us about after telling us about X.

Comment: OK, here's a real world example of if/else: "If the trains are running, I'll go by train, otherwise I'll take the bus." -> `if (isTrainRunning) { goByTrain(); } else { goByBus(); }` - by using `if/else if` you are combining unrelated things. If someone said to you "if the trains are running, I'll go by train. Otherwise, I'll buy some eggs." doesn't really make sense as a course of action dependent on the trains not running, right? That would be `if (isTrainRunning) { goByTrain(); } else { buyEggs(); }`. You want something like `if (isTrainRunning) { goByTrain(); } if (needEggs) { buyEggs(); }`

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar my main goal is to print the total of all checkboxes that are currently checked. So far, if I tick more than one checkbox it will only print the value of the first checkbox, which I understand why it does. So I am trying to figure out a way that will enable me to print the sum total of the checkboxes that ARE checked

Comment: Again, apologies as I am still very new to programming. I understand how if else statements work, but not really sure of a better way to go about this. Maybe a for loop? But then not sure how to implement a for loop to make my problem work

Comment: `int extras = (checkBox1.Checked ? 0 : access) + (checkBox2.Checked ? 0 : onLineVideos) + (checkBox3.Checked ? 0 : personalTrainer) + (checkBox4.Checked ? 0 : dietConsultation);`

Comment: @cakeuwaifu If you find the solution, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you don't need multiple if/else clauses, but only a method which sums all values of your check boxes whose state is checked. Something like this:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if((c is CheckBox) && ((CheckBox) c).Checked)
      {
        yourdecimal += Convert.ToDecimal(c.Text); 
      }                
}
```

The exact method depends on your exact code, so it might be required to change the "this.Controls" as example. Or it might be necessary to add try/catch to prevent issues if there are non numeric values etc. This is just a way to do this. If you need further assistance, you should please add your source code.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am still a bit stuck, apologies, like I said I am very new to coding so this is all hard for me to understand. Can you please explain what the for loop does in your example?

Comment: The foreach will find every checkbox existing within your form. Then it checks for each checkbox whether it is checked. If it's checked, its value will be added to the decimal "yourdecimal", so this decimal will sum all values of all checked checkboxes you have. And this is your goal according to your description?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code a bit with a help of ternary operators:

```
int extras = (checkBox1.Checked ? 0 : access) + 
             (checkBox2.Checked ? 0 : onLineVideos) + 
             (checkBox3.Checked ? 0 : personalTrainer) + 
             (checkBox4.Checked ? 0 : dietConsultation);
```

A better option is to *separate* data (options' prices) and logic:

```
using System.Linq;

...

// Data: option and its price
var prices = new (CheckBox option, int price)[] {
  (checkBox1,  1),
  (checkBox2,  2),
  (checkBox3, 20),
  (checkBox4, 20),
};

...

// Logic: we sum all checked options
var extras = prices.Sum(item => item.option.Checked ? item.price : 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the solution by @jonas-metzler, you can create a sort-of mapping table (`Dictionary`) between checkboxes and their values. This can be used if you're using `Text` property on the `Checkbox` for something else or as a more general-purpose solution for similar problems outside WinForms.

```
var checkboxValues = new Dictionary<Checkbox, int>
{
    { checkBox1, access },
    { checkBox2, onlineVideos },
    { checkBox3, personalTrainer },
    { checkBox4, dietConsultation },
};

var sum = checkboxValues.Where(kvPair => kvPair.Key.Checked)
    .Sum(kvPair => kvPair.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting, too. The question is so general that there are 1000 possibilities to implement this ;) You can even include the foreach in your dictionary, to avoid entering each check box manually.

Comment: @cakeuwaifu What part of it is not working for you? You can check out [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a2PGri) to see it in action.

Comment: Of course, these solutions do work. And there is no solution which is even more simple then a foreach over all checkboxes or this dictionary here. If you are not able to implement this, you should upload your entire project or you have to find out what you did wrong.